# Program to design basic 2D roads, intersection, and highways (without complicated civil engineering features)

Tags: windows, design

I am not an engineer (well, not civil or traffic anyways), but I am interested in making 2D designs / schematic of intersection, roads and highways.

Programs such as AutoCAD or RoadEng do offer this 'feature'; however, it is way too in depth for me (such as road grading, surfaces, 3D geometry, limitations, etc...).

I just want to design 2D roads, with some basic dimensions' measurement, sign and other objects placements, labels, 2D curves, repeatability (easy drawing/placement of chevrons, markings, arrows).  Similar to the images below:

[image: roundabout with clear footpath and xing]

[image: stright road]

[image: t intersection]

Price preference: Free, but paid would be fine too.
OS: Windows 11

Any help with finding the software for those tasks would be appreciated; or if you have some trick to make AutoCAD/RoadEng easier for those tasks and ignore other features meant for real civil engineers, please detail it.

Comment: Welcome P. Z.!  Do you have any OS preference or price range?  If so, please edit your question and tags to reflect them.  Thanks, and again, welcome!

Comment: I have updated :)

Comment: Looks great! Great job in figuring out the correct Windows tag to use, as it can be a source of confusion.  Thank you!